# number formed by inserting odd number of zeros between two ones

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

we know that $101$ is a prime number. similarly $10001$ is also prime. Can we have a general proof that number with trailing ones and odd number of zeros between them is Prime. That is if

$$N=100000\cdots0001$$ with $2k+1$ zeros can be written as

$$N=1+10^{2k+2}$$ how can we prove that any number of this form is Prime.

Comment: $10001 = 73\cdot 137$

Comment: oh thank you, i could not factor it

Comment: It's easy enough to prove that if such a number is prime, then it is of the form $1+100^{2^k}$. (But no numbers other than $101$ of that form appear to be prime, at least as far as my computer can compute, which is to $k=12$)

Comment: Note that if $10^m + 1$ is a prime, then $m$ is a power of $2$. But, like for the Fermat numbers $F_k = 2^{2^k} + 1$, not many primes of the form $10^{2^k} + 1$ are known (I think only $10^{2^0} + 1 = 11$ and $10^{2^1} + 1 = 101$).

Comment: Recently, there was a qeustion about the prime numbers of the form $10^n+1$. Probably, $2$, $11$ and $101$ are the only ones.